# where are dependencies installed in the production server?

Tags: grails-2.2

I am using Grails 2.2 and the plugins are really old. For some reason the dependencies are not resolving. I think it used to work because the plugins and files were in my local cache. From the documentation grails stores the dependencies locally in home/.grails/ivy-cache

> With all these declarative dependencies, you may wonder where all the
>   JARs end up. They have to go somewhere after all. By default Grails
>   puts them into a directory, called the dependency cache, that resides
>   on your local file system at user.home/.grails/ivy-cache. You can
>   change this either via the settings.groovy file:

So the only option i can think of is to go to my remote server and find this directory to copy the dependencies to my local system. So where is this ivy-cache directory in production server? I dont seem to find it. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same issue also I was working in the last week, from 15th January maven had decommissioned the http protocol where the URL "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/" has changed to"https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/". Also need to check the grails maven to secured.

In BuilConfig.groovy, you can add the dependencies and the changed maven repo else in the _Events.groovy need to change the repo address to secure protocol.

If still you have protocol issue because of JDK8 try this -`Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2` in the path or bat file.

Comment: thanks for the response. i am using grails 2.2 and jdk 7. So do you think by using this url in build config this problem is solved. https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ Ill try tomorrow. thanks!